# User creation failing due to integrity constraint violation

Tags: 7, users, database

For reasons I can't understand, I am unable to create users in my Drupal installation (which wasn't a problem last time I tried).

If I try in the UI (at `/admin/people/create`) or if I try with `drush user-create`, in both cases the error message I get reads like:

```
WD rules: Unable to modify data "account:field-user-image:alt": Invalid data value given.
↪  Be sure it matches [warning] the required data type and format.
WD rules: Unable to evaluate action data_set.
WD user: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
↪ entry '187810' for key[error] 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {users} (uid, name, pass, mail,
↪ created, access, status, data) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_7);
Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 187810
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => $S$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1329491489
    [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0
    [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1
    [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => a:1:{s:34:"user_relationships_ui_auto_approve";a:0:{}}
)
 in drupal_write_record() (line 6975 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc).
WD php: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate
↪ entry '187810' for key[error] 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {users} (uid, name, pass, mail,
↪ created, access, status, data) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_7);
Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 187810
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => $S$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1329491489
    [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0
    [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1
    [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => a:1:{s:34:"user_relationships_ui_auto_approve";a:0:{}}
)
 in drupal_write_record() (line 6975 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc).
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
↪ &#039;187810&#039; for key &#039;PRIMARY&#039;: INSERT INTO {users} (uid, name,
↪ pass, mail, created, access, status, data) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
↪ :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 187810
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => $S$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1329491489
    [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0
    [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1
    [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => a:1:{s:34:"user_relationships_ui_auto_approve";a:0:{}}
)
 in drupal_write_record() (line 6975 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

(where `↪` indicates that I've wrapped lines for legibility).

Now I can see that this is because it is trying to enter a duplicate `users.uid` into the database, but I can't work out why that would be the case. At no point have we manually entered `users.uid` values, so the `autoincrement` should just be doing its thing.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there some way for me to reset something so that Drupal (or mySQL) just resets its autoincrement value and tries to do the insert with a valid UID?

Alternately, should I just mess with the database manually? It'd be awkward to do, as there are a surprising number of fields to have to mess with, but I could do that if it's easier?

**Update:** A friend suggested running [`mysqlcheck`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html), but that is passing ok. Also, [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive)'s [suggestion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/22914/3966) of resetting the autoincrement for the table doesn't seem to have resolved the problem.

Comment: What's the very first line doing? Do you have Rules triggers on user creation? Try disabling rules.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the first line is just a validation error message for one of the fields I'm not specifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a *really* long time getting *really* frustrated with this, I've just fixed it *with one line of SQL*. (Some days I really hate computers.)

The database table `sequences` contains one row and one column. This `sequences.value` is the `autoincrement` ID that is used for (amongst other things) new user accounts.

I don't know why it was wrong or how it got wrong. But

```
mysql> update sequences set value = 200000;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

and suddenly user account creation works again.

Did I mention that some days I really hate computers? ;o)

Comment: Except that our daily "make sure the user database is up-to-date with the third party it comes from" script has run and now it doesn't work again. `sequences.value` is `200083` and the ID that user creation is trying with is `200004`. Stupid `autoincrement`-misuse!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem and traced it to Rules.  A thread about rules causing this error can be found here:
http://drupal.org/node/1169800

Comment: Fixing the rules problem at the start of the error log still leaves me with the `PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '200015' for key 'PRIMARY'` message afterwards. Which is all the more confusing because `sequences.value` is `200266`, the same as the value I get from `select max(uid) from users;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the auto increment value fairly easily:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 187811
```

It is a bit strange though, when you add a user the `uid` is determined with the line of code:

```
$account->uid = db_next_id(db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField());
```

As that grabs the maximum user id out of the database and uses PDO to get the next available ID I'm not sure if the auto increment field actually comes into it.

Either way it's worth running the alter query against the table, it might do the trick.

Comment: As you feared, it is still grabbing a (different) `uid` from the table. I reset with `alter table users auto_increment = 200000;` (as the `max(uid)` was `190018`), but trying again and it's now trying a `uid` of `187818`.